# NaN node positions after setting initial position in d3 force-directed network

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm creating a force-directed network in D3 where each node represents a webpage in a collection and directed links between them represent a hyperlink from one webpage to another. As the user moves between webpages, links are added to the network. The number of nodes/webpages in the collection doesn't change.

Whenever a new link is added, I reload the network, reading in JSON code containing the new and old links and all the nodes. At the moment, I'm trying to "calm" the initial loading of this network so that nodes aren't created at random places, potentially creating a network where the nodes are nowhere near where they were before. To do this, I want to set the initial position of each node to what it was in the previous network.

I've done this by setting the node's x and y attributes as seen in the following code snippet:

```
var links = data.links;
var nodes = data.nodes;

var nodeDictionary = new Object();
if (node != 0) {
    force.stop();

    node.each(function(d) {
        var pos = [];
        var thisNode = d3.select(this);
        pos[0] = thisNode.attr("x");
        pos[1] = thisNode.attr("y");
        var page = thisNode.attr("page");
        nodeDictionary[page] = pos;
    });

    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
        var x = nodeDictionary[node.id][0];
        var y = nodeDictionary[node.id][1];

        //node.px = undefined;
        //node.py = undefined;
        node.x = x;
        node.y = y;
    });
}
```

This seems to work some of the time or for some nodes, but most of the time this results in the nodes having NaN positions. Specifically, these positions are NaN in the tick() method of the network, which looks like this:

```
// Animates the force-directed network
function tick() {
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    link.attr("d", drawCurve);
}

function drawCurve(d) {
    var testing = "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    return testing
}
```

In other examples I've seen where an initial node position is set in a force-directed network, the tick() method looks more like this:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

Is there something else I need to do to make my code work using the translate function? I've tried stopping the tick method before creating a new network as suggested in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/k6VSYZfMjGA as well, but that didn't help. Do I need to clear some variable or element before generating a new network?  I've also tried setting the px and py attributes and the px, py, x, and y attributes with various combinations of values with no success.

I've created a jsfiddle with the basic code showing the problem I'm experiencing here: http://jsfiddle.net/ew5qprhe/1/
Double clicking any of the nodes will cause a new network to be generated. Some of the nodes are correctly set to their previous positions, but ones with NaN positions move to the upper left corner.

Comment: That code snippet is seriously messed up, but I'm gonna guess that the `id` property in your data set is not always equal to the "page" attribute you're extracting from the `<text>` elements.

Comment: Sorry for the strange code. The page attribute is supposed to match the id. Doing a quick test, it looks like each node is assigned an x and a y as expected. The position stored in nodeDictionary using the page attribute matches the position assigned to the node with the matching id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was to change this business:

```
node.each(function(d) {
    var pos = [];
    var thisNode = d3.select(this);
    pos[0] = thisNode.attr("x");
    pos[1] = thisNode.attr("y");
    var page = thisNode.attr("page");
    nodeDictionary[page] = pos;
});
```

to this:

```
node.each(function(d) {
    pos = [];
    pos[0] = d.x;
    pos[1] = d.y;
    var page = d.id;
    nodeDictionary[page] = pos;
});
```

Strange things were happening because of my use of .attr("x") and .attr("y"). Also, curse my unfamiliarity with D3!

Comment: Hmm, I must be getting my `NaN`'s for a different reason.  Note that the first three lines can be written as `pos = [d.x, d.y]`.